# Wrong operator precedence with Happy

Tags: parsing, haskell, operator-precedence, happy

Exploring parsing libraries in Haskell I came across this project: [haskell-parser-examples](https://github.com/ghulette/haskell-parser-examples). Running some examples I found a problem with the operator precedence. It works fine when using Parsec:

```
$ echo "3*2+1" | dist/build/lambda-parsec/lambda-parsec
Op Add (Op Mul (Num 3) (Num 2)) (Num 1)
Num 7
```

But not with Happy/Alex:

```
$ echo "3*2+1" | dist/build/lambda-happy-alex/lambda-happy-alex
Op Mul (Num 3) (Op Add (Num 2) (Num 1))
Num 9
```

Even though the operator precedence seems well-defined. Excerpt from the [parser](https://github.com/ghulette/haskell-parser-examples/blob/master/happy-parser-src/Parser.y):

```
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'

%%

Exprs : Expr                             { $1 }
      | Exprs Expr                       { App $1 $2 }

Expr : Exprs                             { $1 }
     | let var '=' Expr in Expr end      { App (Abs $2 $6) $4 }
     | '\\' var '->' Expr                { Abs $2 $4 }
     | Expr op Expr                      { Op (opEnc $2) $1 $3 }
     | '(' Expr ')'                      { $2 }
     | int                               { Num $1 }
```

Any hint? (I opened a [bug report](https://github.com/ghulette/haskell-parser-examples/issues/1) some time ago, but no response).

[Using gch 7.6.3, alex 3.1.3, happy 1.19.4]

Comment: I think the problem is that even though precedence levels are defined for `+`,`-`,`*`, and `/`, those don't affect the generated parser at all.  The only rule that applies is `Expr op Expr`, so essentially all the ops have the same precedence.  This could probably be fixed by using the operators as tokens in `Expr` instead of having the separate `opEnc` rule.

Comment: @JohnL You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in haskell-parser-examples' usage of token precedence.  Happy's operator precedence only affects the rules that use the tokens directly.  In the parser we want to apply precedence to the `Expr` rule, but the only applicable rule,

```
| Expr op Expr { Op (opEnc $2) $1 $3 }
```

doesn't use tokens itself, instead relying on `opEnc` to expand them.  If `opEnc` is inlined into `Expr`,

```
| Expr '*' Expr { Op Mul $1 $3 }
| Expr '+' Expr { Op Add $1 $3 }
| Expr '-' Expr { Op Sub $1 $3 }
```

it should work properly.